# update date dynamically on jsp page

Tags: jsp, tags

I use custom tag to get current date.

```
public int doStartTag() {

    log.info("try to init JSpWriter");
    JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();

    log.info("try to get date");
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        out.println(printFormat.format(new Date()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(null, e);
    }

    return SKIP_BODY;

}
```

And use it on page like this `<span class="date"><d:DateTag /></span>`.

But how to update it dynamically? Because it is static and it changes when I update page.

Comment: Use JavaScript. Google for "digital clock in JavaScript"

Comment: But I want to use tag.

Comment: A tag is used to generate HTML on the server. Once the HTML is in the browser, if you want to update it every second, you'd better use JavaScript. A screwdriver is not the right tool to dig a hole. A JSP tag is not the right tool to constantly change text on a web page.

Comment: I need to use custom tag - it's a task - but I don't have any ideas except date and language.

Comment: Then make sure your custom tag generates the JavaScript necessary to update the time every second in the browser.

Comment: oh! so how it will look like - I mean what to add to the page or to DateTag class?

Comment: Google for "digital clock in JavaScript"